# php like associative arrays in Groovy

Tags: groovy, associative-array

I'm coming from the PHP world and I need to do do some tallying of records.  In php I know this is simple, but how do I do the following in Groovy

```
$logs = array( array( 'date' => '5-15', 'name' => 'foo' ...other stuff),
               array( 'date' => '5-15', 'name' => 'bar' ...other stuff),
               array( 'date' => '5-16', 'name' => 'foo' ...other stuff),
               array( 'date' => '5-17', 'name' => 'foo' ...other stuff),
               array( 'date' => '5-17', 'name' => 'foo' ...other stuff),
               array( 'date' => '5-17', 'name' => 'bar' ...other stuff),
               array( 'date' => '5-17', 'name' => 'bar' ...other stuff) );

$counts = array();

foreach($logs as $log) {
   if( isset($counts[ $log['date'] ][ $log['name'] ]) ) {
       $counts[ $log['date'] ][ $log['name'] ] = 1;
   } else {
       $counts[ $log['date'] ][ $log['name'] ]++;
   }
}
```

which gives me the result

```
['5-15']['foo'] = 1
['5-15']['bar'] = 1
['5-16']['foo'] = 1
['5-17']['foo'] = 2
['5-17']['bar'] = 2
```

Logs is actually my result set returned from a GORM query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Groovy [countBy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#countBy%28groovy.lang.Closure%29).

`def map = logs.countBy{[it.date, it.name]}`

You would end up with a map of results and corresponding count. In your case it will be like

`[[5-15, foo]:1, [5-15, bar]:1, [5-16, foo]:1, [5-17, foo]:2, [5-17, bar]:2]`

**Sample**

```
def logs = [
        [ date: '5-15', name: 'foo'],
        [ date: '5-15', name: 'bar'],
        [ date: '5-16', name: 'foo'],
        [ date: '5-17', name: 'foo'],
        [ date: '5-17', name: 'foo'],
        [ date: '5-17', name: 'bar'],
        [ date: '5-17', name: 'bar']]

def map = logs.countBy{[it.date, it.name]}

assert map[['5-15', 'foo']] == 1
assert map[['5-15', 'bar']] == 1
assert map[['5-16', 'foo']] == 1
assert map[['5-17', 'foo']] == 2
assert map[['5-17', 'bar']] == 2
```

If you need to get `each` of the `<key,value>` pair from the map. You can very well do like:-

```
map.each{k, v ->
    println "$k has been used $v times"
}

//Prints:
[5-15, foo] has been used 1 times
[5-15, bar] has been used 1 times
[5-16, foo] has been used 1 times
[5-17, foo] has been used 2 times
[5-17, bar] has been used 2 times
```

*Tested in Groovy 2.1.3*

Comment: This is working and when I debug log print the object it contains all the values exactly as expected, but when I try to get a specific value from the map I'm getting NULL.

Comment: Try the same assertions my dear friend which was used by @BDKosher. See my update as well.

Comment: @MikeLP Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

This is using a compound key in the counts map. You could slice and dice it other ways, though.

```
def logs = [
        [ date: '5-15', name: 'foo'],
        [ date: '5-15', name: 'bar'],
        [ date: '5-16', name: 'foo'],
        [ date: '5-17', name: 'foo'],
        [ date: '5-17', name: 'foo'],
        [ date: '5-17', name: 'bar'],
        [ date: '5-17', name: 'bar']]

def counts = [:]         
logs.collectEntries(counts) { 
    def key = [it.date, it.name]
    def count = counts[key] ?: 0
    [key, count + 1]
}


assert counts[['5-15', 'foo']] == 1
assert counts[['5-15', 'bar']] == 1
assert counts[['5-16', 'foo']] == 1
assert counts[['5-17', 'foo']] == 2
assert counts[['5-17', 'bar']] == 2
```